# EXT-JS topic - errors when follow getting started tutorial

Tags: extjs

this days I wanna check'out something about ExtJs and I jumped on here for the [GettingStartedTut](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/getting_started/mobile_desktop_application/getting_started_with_npm.html?utm_source=sncln&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pt_purchase&utm_content=tnc-extjs-community-ty-1)

At step 4 I run npmstart but some Errors appears like... I cannot attach the Sencha Cmd 7.7.0.36 - Crash report, i try later.
That's it,

```
`https://pastebin.com/embed_js/MV22JfaD`
```

Launch of Npm Start command and a list of error is outputted on my window CLI.
I don't know what Java has to do with it...

Comment: what is the java version you are using?

Comment: @shae running the `java -version` cmd it say openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
Do you mean that a downgrade or upgrade could potentially solve the thing?

Comment: Cool..All extjs products supports java 8-11. I thought you might be using higher version. I can see you were following tutorial steps on 7.0.0-CE!

Comment: Also try checkout latest version documentation to create that might resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which might helps!

Refer the below doc to reset the npm first,
[NPM RESET LINK](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/guides/using_systems/using_npm/npm_help.html#using_systems-_-using_npm/npm_help_-__npm_reset_)

And now try creating a new app using npm by following the steps mentioned in the link below:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_npm.html

Comment: ok ! thanks for help... i will try and flag the Solved button ;)